# When I launch blender I already have fill problems

Tags: faces, edges, loop

When I launch blender and I duplicate the base cube, and then I try to fill both sides, here are the results I get, I can't use the select loop on the edges of the cubes , (I have reinstall blender with a newer version

[image]

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Trying to fill both sides of what? I'f you've duplicated the base cube in Object mode you'll have two seperate objects and you won't be able to fill the gap between them, whereas if you duplicate in Edit mode you'll still have a single object and can fill in faces between the two cubes.

Comment: even if we do ctrl j?

Comment: Sure but they won't be seperate objects if you do that. Your image doesn't really show what you are trying to fill. Can you add another image from a different angle, maybe with an annotation showing what you are actually trying to fill (and one in Edit mode would help too)?

Comment: Yes it's my fault